# Are mutually-dependent child/parent namespaces a code smell?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, namespaces, dependencies

I was looking at some dependency graphs for my primary personal project recently, and I noticed that I had a mutual dependency between objects in nested namespaces.  E.g., I had an object in `MyNamespace.Foo` that implemented a generic interface in `MyNamespace.Foo.Interfaces` with that object as the generic parameter in the interface.

```
namespace MyNamespace.Foo
{
    internal class Foo : MyNamespace.Foo.Interfaces.IFoo<Foo>
    { }
}
```

In this case. the dependency analysis tool (VS2010 beta) reasonably considers the generic "instantiation" (for the sake of discussion, I know this isn't c++) of the interface to be a member of Interfaces namespace that then depends on its parent namespace.

After some consideration on my part, I've more-or-less reached the conclusion that my existing design, in my particular case, is a code-smell.  I should merge the `Interfaces` namespace into the parent Foo namespace.  (It's silly to require clients to drill down an extra layer to the interfaces namespace if I want them to use `Foo` via `IFoo`.)  Is this true in the general case, however?

How should inter-namespace dependencies be managed?  Should "broader" namespaces (like `MyNamespace.Foo` generally depend on "narrower" namespaces (like `MyNamespace.Foo.Interfaces`), or should narrower namespaces depend on broader ones?  Or is there some better, more subtle answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the specific case regarding your example, I would merge the `Interfaces` namespace into the parent namespace.

In general, I think that narrower namespaces should depend on classes or interfaces from broader ones, or ones that are a child of a shared parent namespace.  The second case is typical if you have your namespaces arranged so that a model namespace has shared classes or interfaces that describe your model for the problem your code is trying to solve.

I should also note that I don't think these rules necessarily apply to third-party dependencies.  For example, depending on a code from a narrow namespace in [Spring.NET](http://springframework.net/) in your code doesn't constitute a code-smell.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to separate interface from implementation, a possibility would be parallel MyNamespace.Foo.Interfaces and MyNamespace.Foo.Implementation namespaces.

The default seems to be that a namespace is equivalent to a package or assembly: so `Foo` and `Bar` would be the namespaces for `foo.dll` and `bar.dll` respectively.

I'll add prefixes to the namespace if I want higher-level groupings: for example `MyCorp.Server.Foo` is the namespace for the server-side `foo.dll` produced by MyCorp.

Note that I'm adding prefixes, not suffixes: so `MyCorp.Server.Foo` rather than `Foo.Server.MyCorp`. These structured namespaces correspond to the folder/directory structures in which the source code and the projects are contained.

By default, everything file in a package will have the same namespace (e.g. all code in `foo.dll` belongs to the `MyCorp.Server.Foo` namespace). If I do ever add a suffix, this has the effect of hiding that code from the rest of the assembly. For example, code in the `MyCorp.Server.Foo.EditorTransactions` namespace exists in the `foo.dll` but isn't seen by most of the other code in `foo.dll` (except code which explicitly uses `MyCorp.Server.Foo.EditorTransactions`).